# Create Hidden Association in PHP/MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL Db that has a PROFILE-TABLE as well as a KEYWORD-TABLE which holds profiles and the other holds keywords associated with those categories.

**Profile-Table**

  UserID
  UserName
  UserDept
  UserPhoto
  UserKeyword > indexes KeywordName (from Keyword-Table)
  UserAssociations

**Keyword-Table**

  KeyID
  KeywordName

I need to make an association with the categories/keywords.

I want to add a hidden field (UserAssociations) onto my profile form which will display a hidden association where as when you click on a category via a link on the page, it will index first those that are associated. I have written this in PHP and use MYSQLI database.

I have never created associations before needing this. What would be the easiest way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. You say you want to create a relation then ask about creating an index.

Comment: I don't remember asking about creating an index ??

Comment: "it will index first those that are associated" AFAIK you can't conditionally index rows

Comment: but that's not a question... @MikeB

Comment: Your question is "What would be the easiest way to achieve this functionality?" Which includes your entire question.

Comment: Since you accepted the answer it must mean you're interested in normal form and many-to-many relations. Extra reading, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_Entities, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model), http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: thanks @MikeB ill give it a look... but as far as what I had already tried it looks like Extrakun's idea logically fits my concept. I'll read up on those links you provided as well... btw, Wikipedia is not the best web reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I gather, you wish to associate a user profile with keyword. What you need is another table to represent the relationship, something like this:

```
profile_keywords ( <UserID>, <KeyID> )
```

Hence, if UserID 4 has associated himself with keyword ID 3, you would have an entry in profile_keywords like this:

```
UserID, KeyID
---------------
   3      4
```

Comment: this is exactly what I am needing... logically this makes sense and is doable.